# Proving uniqueness using $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, soft-question

I remember in the beginning of my undergrad linear differential equations class (while or before we were introduced to linear ODE's), we proved the uniqueness of a solution to an IVP by taking the partial derivative with respect to $y$ of *something* (might have been part of the equation, or the solution itself), concluded that the derivative was continuous on the necessary interval, and concluded that the solution is unique. Does anybody know of any techniques (reasonably taught in an undergrad DE class) that use the continuity of  $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}$ to prove the uniqueness of a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you are referring to to the celebrated Picard-Lindelöf theorem which is an existence and uniqueness theorem for ordinary differential equations of the form $y'(t) = f(t,y(t))$. Here $f$ should be continuous and uniformly Lipschitz continuous in the spatial variable(s) in a neighborhood of the initial condition. This second condition is frequently established by assuming that $f$ is differentiable with respect to the spatial variable(s) with continuous derivative(s). In the case of one spatial variable, the partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ is *the* central figure.

It is very reasonable to see the Picard-Lindelöf theorem during the second year of undergraduate studies.